# Ajax is event is multiplying with each click

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, coffeescript

I have a simple commenting function that asynchronously posts the comment to the DB and the page.  However, each time I click the button the action multiplies, 1, 2, 4, 8...

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<h3> comments: </h3>
<ol id="comments">
    <% @comments.each do |c| %>
        <li><%= c.body %></li>
    <% end %>
</ol>
</div.>

<%= form_for(@comment, remote: true) do |f| %>
 <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :comment %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :body %>
 </div>

    <%= f.submit :value => "submit comment", :class => "btn btn-default", :type => "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

and here is the JS.Coffee:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#new_comment").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    $('#comments').append(xhr.responseText)
    # $('#new_comment')[0].reset();

  ).on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    $("#new_comment").append "<p>ERROR</p>"
```

[image]

Any idea what's happening??

Comment: it could be that... you are running the script which registers the click handler in another event handler...  so whenever that handler is executed  a new click handler is added to the existing step

Comment: can you add a console log/alert statement in the dom ready handler to see whetehr it is executed multiple times

Comment: @ArunPJohny So I need to disable the '#new_comment' on the call? What do you suggest?

Comment: I added an alert, and the alert is popping up multiple times.  @ArunPJohny

Comment: that is the problem... is the script inside a dynamically loaded content?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I don't think so...

Comment: Without the complete picture a solution may not be possible... for now as a hack you can try `$("#new_comment:not(.ajaxified)").addClass('ajaxified').on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->`

Comment: @ArunPJohny so I changed my file it was loading to a partial, and that helped with the duplication.  However, now I am get a JSON item in quotes, so it looks like this...
"id":81,"body":"jlklkjjkllkj","created_at":"2015-04-06T03:59:48.565Z","updated_at":"2015-04-06T03:59:48.565Z"}

Comment: http://imgur.com/pUzzkmv @ArunPJohny

Comment: so what do you want to be displayed?

Comment: Okay, I got the text I want and it's appending, however it isn't a list item anymore.  So it's appending correctly but it's not numbered in the list.

`$(document).ready ->`
`  $("#new_comment").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->`
`   response = JSON.parse xhr.responseText`
`   console.log(response)`
`   $('#comments').append(response.body) `
`   # $('#new_comment')[0].reset();`
`   alert('hello');`
`  ).on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->`
`    $("#new_comment").append "<p>ERROR</p>"`